# Converting country names into thier own ThreeLetterISORegionName with RegionInfo (c# 2013 Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, regioninfo

I’ve already written every country’s name in a ComboBox but now i want  to get each country’s ThreeLetterISORegionName when i click the country’s name in the ComboBox and display it in a label, is that possible? 
Thanks

Comment: You can use this class: [Get ISO country code from country name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49313331/7444103). Adapt it as required, it's all already there. Maybe add a property if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ComboBox's SelectedIndexChanged event, you could declare a new RegionInfo from the selected country, determine its ThreeLetterISORegionName, and set the label to it, like so:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString());
        Label1.Text = ri.ThreeLetterISORegionName;
    }
```

Comment: This works but only if i have the Two letter code of the country, i wnat to get the country’s 3 letter when i click on the country’s full name, for example if i click on “United States” in my ComboBox, my label should display “USA”.

Comment: Oh, I see. You may try declaring the RegionInfo using the country name like was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262021/get-regioninfo-by-country-name)

Comment: Exactly, this will do it. Thanks for the help