# Language ID from file resource

Tags: c#, winapi

I use Visual Studio C#. I need to get the language ID and charset ID from a file's resources.

I can get the language from the `FileVersionInfo` resource:

```
public static string getFileLang(string file)
{
  FileVersionInfo moduleVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(file);
  return moduleVersionInfo.Language;
}
```

However, this returns a string value like "English (USA)". How to get the language ID and charset ID of the file as a number?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/varfileinfo-block

Comment: Your question is not related to winforms and Visual Studio, so I removed these tags

Comment: [Get ISO country code from country name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49313331/7444103)

Comment: @KlausGütter Not sure this is really a WinAPI question. I'm no real C# expert but isn't that tag for **native** Windows applications?

Comment: @AdrianMole I added the tag because the OP linked to WinAPI docs. And a solution using P/Invoke would be possible.

Comment: @Klaus OK, that makes sense. It would be interesting to know if the call to 'GetVersionInfo` is implemented the same way on non-Windows platforms, though.

Comment: Seems on Unix, only the managed assembly metadata is read, and `Language` is always "Language Neutral". See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo/src/System/Diagnostics/FileVersionInfo.Unix.cs

Answer (score 1):

To get the language ID ("LCID") value from the name you retrieve (which is the "Display name" for the language in question), you need to loop through your system's known cultures and test for a match with the `DisplayName` field in each culture; if found, then the `LCID` field (an `int`) will be the answer you want:

```cs
public static int getFileLCID(string file)
{
    int LCID = 0;
    FileVersionInfo moduleVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(file);
    string dispName = moduleVersionInfo.Language;
    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
    foreach (CultureInfo test in cultures)
    {
        if (dispName == test.DisplayName) return test.LCID;
    }
    return 0; // Not found!
}
```

Note that you will need a `using System.Globalization;` directive in your source code for the `CultureInfo` class.

Edit: A more 'thorough' test loop – which *may* be necessary for some platforms or cultures – would involve testing the returned language name against the system cultures' `EnglishName` and `NativeName` fields, as well as the `DisplayName`:

```cs
    foreach (CultureInfo test in cultures)
    {
        if (dispName == test.DisplayName ||
            dispName == test.EnglishName ||
            dispName == test.NativeName) return test.LCID;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that information on the (default) character set a program uses is even embedded in the file's resources. That may be something you would have to query from a *running instance* of the program. But I could be wrong.

Comment: It's work, Thank you. Maybe you know how to get charset ID?

Comment: @Sem I'm looking into the CharSet problem but - from what I have discovered so far - that information doesn't appear to be tied to a particular "culture" (which is what the field in the `FileVersionInfo` resource actually specifies).